# усовершенствование скрипта по рандомному подбору видео

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, if

Господа всем привет,задача состоит в следующем ,есть готовый скрипт который создает iframe и рандомит в него ссылку на видео,таким образом при нажатии на определенную клавишу рандомно выводит видео пользователю,у меня возникла задача которую не знаю как реализовать,нужно чтобы при входе на страницу пользователю выбивало окошко где он выбирал возраст и галочками мог выбрать к примеру -смешное - страшное -екшн и по выбору одного или всех критериев при учете так же возраста ему подбиралось уже по скрипту соответствующие видео) задача не простая знаю что должна быть проверка if-else но не знаю как правильно реализовать с окошком при входе,вод сам скрипт и div блок 
та же клавиша,пользователь так же должен при нажатии получать случайное видео,но уже с учетом всех выборов сделаных в начале,тоесть должно быть уже несколько масивов с ссылками и при нажатии задействовался тот масив который подпадает под критерий выбраный в начале пользователем.

```
 const button = document.querySelector('button');
    const container = document.querySelector('.containers');
    const iframe = document.createElement('iframe'); //Создаем элемент
    iframe.className = "yourclass"; //Добавляем к нему необходимый класс(ы)
    container.appendChild(iframe); //вставляем как дочерний элемент к 
 определенному контейнеру
    const links = [
        "https://topkino.club/embed/943779/",
        "https://topkino.club/embed/1009236/",
        "https://topkino.club/embed/893988/"
    ];

    const getRandomInt = (size = links.length) => {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * size);
    }
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        iframe.src = links[getRandomInt()]; //переназначаем значение 
 атрибута функцией, которая выдает случайные числа
    })
    iframe.setAttribute('allowFullScreen', '');

 function vsbl(){
document.getElementById("films").style.display="block";
 }



  <button onclick="vsbl()" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary 
  cscsc" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Смотреть Кино</button>

  <div id="films" class="containers col-md-12" style='display: none; 
  position: absolute;'>

                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ссылки на видео известны заранее, то можно сделать объекты в которых написать к какой категории относится данное видео

```
{
  videoUrl: 'https://topkino.club/embed/943779/',
  theme: 'comedy'
}
```

Затем в обработчике сортировать список всех видео на основании запроса пользователя и из полученного сортированного списка показывать рандомное видео.

Comment: таких ссылок будут сотни если не тысячи,вот и проблема делать для каждой обьект,также как подключить кнопку к подбору ссылки из таких обьектов..

Comment: В любом случае придется как то делить ссылки. Как вариант брать ссылки сразу сортированными и хранить в разных массивах, а затем в обработчике кнопки проверять что хочет пользователь и брать нужны массив.